# Laravel 5.1 and Backbone.js Application

Tags: api, laravel, backbone.js

I'm new in Backbone and I'm trying to build an app on top of an existing Laravel API. I understand the concept of every Backbone component (Model, Collection, View, Router), but I'm having a bit of trouble defining an architecture for my app. When a user logs in, it gets redirected to a dashboard, with a few options in a navbar.

```
var LeadsView = Backbone.View.extend({});
var SourcesView = Backbone.View.extend({});
var TeamsView = Backbone.View.extend({});

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    // navbar option Leads
    "leads":   "_leadsView",    
    // navbar option Sources
    "sources": "_sourcesView",  
    // navbar option Teams
    "teams":   "_teamsView"  
  },

  _leadsView: function() {
    var leads = new LeadsView();
  },

  _sourcesView: function(query, page) {
    var sources = new SourcesView();
  },

  _teamsView: function(query, page) {
    var teams = new SourcesView();
  },

});
```

I get that a Backbone View acts like a Controller in Laravel, so with each of these defined routes, there's a pointer to a View ( LeadsView, SourcesView, TeamsView). When any one of the views gets instantiated, that view will take care of the model/collection, UI binding, and every other logic for the app interaction. My question is ... Is This approach good, conventional ? If not, how can one use routes to bind each navigation option to an action in Backbone ?

Comment: did you managed to figure out the best practices regarding your issue?